# Build events: copy folder except one file

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In build events I need to copy the whole folder except one specific file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**XCopy** supports an `/Exclude` flag that will do what you want.

From `help xcopy`:

```
/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
```

> Specifies a list of files containing strings.  Each string should be in a separate line in the files.  When any of the strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be copied, that file will be excluded from being copied.  For example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the .obj extension respectively.

So, you'll make a file that contains a list of files to be excluded (one per line), and specify the exclusion file on your xcopy command line.

**Robocopy** also has file exclusion support.

From `robocopy /?`:

```
/XF file [file]...
```

> eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.

This doesn't require an extra exclusion file.  You specify a pattern, instead.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in three easy steps:

1. Create a file, i.e. exclude.txt
2. Add the filenames that you want to exclude
3. Use the following command: `xcopy source target /exclude:exclude.txt`

You can keep exclude.txt in source control.

Tip: if the target is a directory, append it with `\*`, then `xcopy` understands it's a directory and not a file.

Answer (score 1):

do it in 2 steps,

1st copy the entire folder to the new location

2nd delete the file from the newly created folder

Comment: This is all well and good unless the file is something huge like an ISO.  (I'd prefer this solution except in the large-file case, since you don't have to hit the docs to understand it)

Comment: I wouldn't use this when the file triggers something on the target, like web.config, or overwrites something that you want to retain on the target (again: like a web.config or other configuration file).